# Rails - Sidekiq error Uninitialized Constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Can anyone tell me why I am getting the following error from Sidekiq:

`NameError: uninitialized constant ImageWorker::DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT`

## app/models/choice.rb

```
class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base

 #Environment-specific direct upload url verifier screens for malicious posted upload locations.
  DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT = %r{\Ahttps:\/\/s3-us-west-1\.amazonaws\.com\/mybucket\/(?<path>uploads\/.+\/(?<filename>.+))\z}.freeze

  after_commit :queue_processing
  
  protected
  # Queue file processing
    def queue_processing
      ImageWorker.perform_async(id)
    end
end
```

## app/workers/image_worker.rb

```
 class ImageWorker
   include Sidekiq::Worker
   
   def perform(id)
     choice = Choice.find(id)
     direct_upload_url_data = DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT.match(choice.direct_upload_url)
     s3 = AWS::S3.new

     if choice.post_process_required?
       choice.picture = URI.parse(URI.escape(choice.direct_upload_url))
     else
       paperclip_file_path = "documents/uploads/#{id}/original/#{direct_upload_url_data[:filename]}"
    s3.buckets[Rails.configuration.aws[:bucket]].objects[paperclip_file_path].copy_from(direct_upload_url_data[:path])
  end

  choice.processed = true
  choice.save

  s3.buckets[Rails.configuration.aws[:bucket]].objects[direct_upload_url_data[:path]].delete
  end
 end
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **move** the following line to the `ImageWorker` class:

```
DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT = %r{\Ahttps:\/\/s3-us-west-1\.amazonaws\.com\/mybucket\/(?<path>uploads\/.+\/(?<filename>.+))\z}.freeze
```

Or, otherwise, use the complete qualified path for the constant: `DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT` like this:

```
direct_upload_url_data = Choice::DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT.match(choice.direct_upload_url)
```

At the moment, your code is trying to locate a constant named `DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT` inside the `ImageWorker` class, which is definitely not initialized, and hence, the error.